# Difference in opening a shared library using libdl API calls

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, loader

Please shed some light on the difference in invoking these two and advice me which is better in terms of performance and efficiency.

```
handle = dlopen("libxx.so", RTLD_GLOBAL| RTLD_NOW);
dlsym(handle, "func");
```

or

```
const char* dlfunc = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "func");
```

This program works for me and gives a valid pointer address:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    /* void* handle = dlopen("libXt.so", RTLD_GLOBAL| RTLD_NOW);
    dlsym(handle, "XtStrings"); */
    const char* dlfunc = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "XtStrings");
    if(!dlfunc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "--- %s\n", dlerror());
    } else {
        printf("DEFAULT: %p\n", dlfunc);
        return;
    }
    dlfunc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "XtStrings");
    if(!dlfunc) fprintf(stderr, "--- %s\n", dlerror());
    printf("NEXT: %p\n", dlfunc);
}
```

compiled using:   gcc  -ldl  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lXt   file.c

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your example code does much useful, and your question cannot be answered, neither is "better" since your 2 snippets of code does different things, e.g. your first code piece loads an additional shared library, while your second code piece does not.

dlopen() allows you to load a shared library.

dlsym() allows you to get a pointer to a symbol in a shared library, or in the currently loaded code (which is the current executable + any shared libraries currently). A symbol can be e.g. a function or a variable.

Here's an example of loading a shared library, and calling a function in that shared library that has the prototype `void func(void)`

```
void *handle = dlopen("libxx.so", RTLD_GLOBAL| RTLD_NOW); //load the shared library
void (*func_ptr)(void)  = dlsym(handle, "func");  //get a pointer to the "func" symbol
func_ptr(); //call the function through our function pointer
```

Here's an example of using dlsym to get a pointer to a function in the currently loaded executable(or any of the currently linked in shared libraries).

```
void (*func_ptr)(void)  = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "func");  //get a pointer to the "func" symbol
func_ptr(); //call the function through our function pointer
```

This latter code could be done by calling the function directly:

```
  func();
```